# Terminar flujo cuando entre en una exception en java

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbc-template

espero y me puedan ayudar con una validación, lo que a grandes rasgos es que tengo una exception que captura error de conexión a la bd, pero el detalle es que si entra pero el proceso continua y ejecuta lo demás, es aplicativo procesa información de archivos de txt, miren, les paso el codigo:

```
        public void procesaInfoSap(JobExecutionContext jobExecContext) {
            block11 : {
                try {
                    if (this.validador.validarEspacioDisponible()) {
                        String rutaBase = this.param.getRutaBase();
                        String rutaFin = String.valueOf(this.param.getRutaBase()) + "/procesados";
                        String rutaGenerados = String.valueOf(this.param.getRutaBase()) + "/generados";
                        String rutaEnviados = String.valueOf(this.param.getRutaBase()) + "/enviados";
                        Integer diaAConsultarArchivo = 0;
                        Calendar fechaActual = Calendar.getInstance();
                        try {
                            diaAConsultarArchivo = Integer.valueOf(this.repo.consultaParametro("DIAACONSULTARARCHIVO"));
    //                        LOGGER.info("Que trae la variable diaAConsultarArchivo" + diaAConsultarArchivo);//JJ
                            if (diaAConsultarArchivo != 0) {
                                //UtilidadEnvioCorreos.enviarCorreo("GAPUUid: Fallo en parametro del DIAACONSULTARARCHIVO", "No se ha podido leer el parametro DIAACONSULTARARCHIVO ",  this.emailMapper.getDistribucionExcepcion());
                                fechaActual.add(5, diaAConsultarArchivo);
                            }
                        }
                      //Inicio JJ
                        catch (CannotGetJdbcConnectionException e) {
                            CannotGetJdbcConnectionException eCGJDBCCEX = e;
                            //if(eCGJDBCCEX.contains(null)) {
                                UtilidadEnvioCorreos.enviarCorreo("GAPUUID no ha podido acceder a los parametros de la bd ", "Error ocurrido: " + eCGJDBCCEX.getMessage(), emailMapper.getDistribucionFalloBD());                           
                            //}                                         
                            
                        }
                        //FIN
                        catch (Exception e) {                       
                            LOGGER.error((Object)"No se ha podido leer el parametro DIAACONSULTARARCHIVO:", (Throwable)e);
                            
                        }
                        String fechaConsulta = FORMATO_FECHA_CONTROL.format(fechaActual.getTime());
                        String patron = "(ffin|FFIN)" + fechaConsulta + ".(txt|TXT)";
                        LOGGER.info((Object)("Se consultara el archivo " + patron));
                        /**Se comenta para test linea 88, pero en producción se descoementa*/
                        //this.descargaArchivosFtp(patron);
                        Map<String, String> lstArchivos = ArchivosUtil.obtenerListaArchivos(rutaBase, patron);
                        LOGGER.info((Object)("Se encontraron " + lstArchivos.size() + " archivos para procesar de fininfosap"));
                        for (Map.Entry<String, String> elementoArchivo : lstArchivos.entrySet()) {
                            List<Fininfosap> registros = this.leerArchivo(elementoArchivo, rutaBase);
                            //JJ
                            if(registros.isEmpty()) {
                                UtilidadEnvioCorreos.enviarCorreo("GAPUUid: Error de lectura archivo ", "El archivo no cumplen con el formato requerido" , this.emailMapper.getDistribucionExcepcion());                    
                            }
                            if (registros.size() <= 0) continue;
                            List<String> lstGenerados = this.generaArchivo(registros, elementoArchivo, rutaBase);
                            ArchivosUtil.moverArchivo(rutaBase, rutaFin, elementoArchivo.getKey());
                            for (String archivoGenerado : lstGenerados) {
                                boolean resultado = ArchivosUtil.transfiereArchivoSFTP(rutaGenerados, archivoGenerado, this.param.getUserDest(), this.param.getPassDest(), this.param.getHostDest(), this.param.getPortDest(), this.param.getRutaDest(), rutaBase);
                                if (!resultado) {
                                    UtilidadEnvioCorreos.enviarCorreo("GAPUUid: Fallo en envio fininfosap", "El proceso fininfosap no ha podido enviar por ftp el archivo: " + archivoGenerado, this.emailMapper.getDistribucionExcepcion());
                                    //continue;
                                }
                                //Inicio JJ
                                else {
                                    
                                    UtilidadEnvioCorreos.enviarCorreo("GAPUUid: Exito en envio fininfosap", "Se ha enviado el archivo: " + archivoGenerado + " Exitosamente ", this.emailMapper.getDistribucionExitoSubidaArchivo());                           
                                    ArchivosUtil.moverArchivo(rutaGenerados, rutaEnviados, archivoGenerado);
                                }
                                //Fin JJ
                                
                            }
                        }
                        patron = "SAP_UUIDINFO_\\d{8}_\\d{6}_\\d{4}\\.(txt|TXT)";
                        Map<String, String> lstArchivosPorEnviar = ArchivosUtil.obtenerListaArchivos(rutaGenerados, patron);
                        for (String archivoPendiente : lstArchivosPorEnviar.keySet()) {
                            boolean resultado = ArchivosUtil.transfiereArchivoSFTP(rutaGenerados, archivoPendiente, this.param.getUserDest(), this.param.getPassDest(), this.param.getHostDest(), this.param.getPortDest(), this.param.getRutaDest(), rutaBase);
                            if (!resultado) {
                                UtilidadEnvioCorreos.enviarCorreo("GAPUUid: Fallo en envio fininfosap", "El proceso fininfosap no ha podido enviar por ftp el archivo: " + archivoPendiente, this.emailMapper.getDistribucionExcepcion());
                                //continue;
                            }
                            ArchivosUtil.moverArchivo(rutaGenerados, rutaEnviados, archivoPendiente);
                        }
                        break block11;
                    }
                    LOGGER.error((Object)"----->>>>> No hay suficiente espacio en disco");
                }
                
                //Inicio JJ
                catch (CannotGetJdbcConnectionException e) {
                    //CannotGetJdbcConnectionException eCGJDBCCEX = e;
                    UtilidadEnvioCorreos.enviarCorreo("Fallo en el proceso fininfosap", "El proceso fininfosap ha tenido un problema no identificado que requiere atencion: " + e.getMessage(), emailMapper.getDistribucionFalloBD());
                }
                //Fin JJ
                
                catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.info((Object)"Se ha producido un error:", (Throwable)e);
                
                }
                
         
            }
        }
```

El problema ya hace todo pero el resultado es que tiene que mandar un solo correo, el metodo del correo son:

```
UtilidadEnvioCorreos.enviarCorreo("GAPUUID no ha podido acceder a los parametros de la bd ", "Error ocurrido: " + eCGJDBCCEX.getMessage(), emailMapper.getDistribucionFalloBD());
```

El codigo de arriba es lo unico que se tendría que validar, pero el problema que se ejecuta el siguiente codigo:

```
for (String archivoGenerado : lstGenerados) {
                        boolean resultado = ArchivosUtil.transfiereArchivoSFTP(rutaGenerados, archivoGenerado, this.param.getUserDest(), this.param.getPassDest(), this.param.getHostDest(), this.param.getPortDest(), this.param.getRutaDest(), rutaBase);
                        if (!resultado) {
                            UtilidadEnvioCorreos.enviarCorreo("GAPUUid: Fallo en envio fininfosap", "El proceso fininfosap no ha podido enviar por ftp el archivo: " + archivoGenerado, this.emailMapper.getDistribucionExcepcion());
                            //continue;
                        }
                        //Inicio JJ
                        else {
                            
                            UtilidadEnvioCorreos.enviarCorreo("GAPUUid: Exito en envio fininfosap", "Se ha enviado el archivo: " + archivoGenerado + " Exitosamente ", this.emailMapper.getDistribucionExitoSubidaArchivo());                           
                            ArchivosUtil.moverArchivo(rutaGenerados, rutaEnviados, archivoGenerado);
                        }
```

El codigo de arriba es basicamente el procesamiento de los archivos en caso de ocurra error regresando true o false, donde dicen las letras JJ son las modificaciones que se hizo, en la parte del catch del jdbc podria venir una validación pero no se como sería la verdad ya hice varios pero ya no se me ocurre como cachar ese error y que ya no se procese:

Así manda los correos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, si hay algo que no se entiende con gusto les aclarare la duda, quedo al pendiente de sus comentarios.

Saludos

Comment: No me queda claro cual es la pregunta..... _en todo caso_, si lo que necesitas es lograr hacer algo con o sin error (como enviar un correo, si entiendo bien?), ese tipo de cosas se hacen con el finally del try. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Comment: Hola Buenas tardes, de echo, ya hasta actualizada, agradezco a la persona que hizo ese detalle, ya se entiende mas, es justo lo que necesito, eso del finally tengo entendido que va al final en mi codigo como podría ser? es decir que en caso que marque error se detenga el flujo

Comment: El finally lo puedes poner como parte adicional a un try.... o sea, es try/catch/finally.... siendo `catch` y `finally` partes opcionales, así que por cada try puede usar un finally, segun lo que necesites. Y el finally de lo que se asegura es de que esa sección que pones en el finally se ejecute con o sin error.... la única excepción a esa regla es que muera la JVM.